# Parsing datetime of the format "2013-Jan-31" throws error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, exception, datetime-parsing

I have a datetime column in database.

```
DateTime end_date = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-Jan-31", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Don't you need `"yyyy-MMM-dd"` as the format (note the extra M)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-Jan-31", "yyyy-MMM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine (a);
```

Output:

```
31.01.2013
```

Look at from MSDN [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is not working because `MM` would mean January to be 01. If this is the format of the date you're trying to parse, try the format `"yyyy-MMM-dd"`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

To use such a name of the month you need to take "MMM" so it will be

```
 myObject.end_date = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-Jan-31", "yyyy-MMM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

`MM` represents a two-digit numerical month (such as "01").

`MMM` represents the abbreviated month (such as "Jan").

Which means that you need

```
myObject.end_date = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-Jan-31", "yyyy-MMM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for a list of string format specifiers.